# Making the cultural culinary feel correct

Tags: internal-consistency, culture, food

Even in places where the same foods are produced and crops do not vary, we tend to see culinary trends. For example, France and Germany have roughly the same climate, a similar landscape but the difference between a spritzkuchen and a croissant is avidly clear. Which had led me to wonder what causes these trends and the best answer to that is simple, food is cultural.

For the sake of an example, let's say my culture lives in central Brazil and thus receive 4-8 months of heavy rain followed by 8-4 of dry season, how do I make my culture's culinary practices feel realistic?

Comment: I feel like there are a number of factors necessary besides location and climate - what plants and animals are available, what the **time period** is, how old the culture is, how complex the culture is, how valued food is (just to eat? for religion? for the pompously rich?). The combination of these and other factors make it so that **there is no "formula" or "equation" -- it completely depends.**

Comment: Given the information in the above comment I don't think you can say "lives in central Brazil" is enough to say "this is what their cuisine is like"; if you want it to "feel" realistic use stereotypes or known examples.

Comment: To amplify Zxyrra's point, culinary norms *in the same places in Europe* in the middle ages, renaissance, and modern times were rather different.  Technology affects food production, and thus what's easy/hard/expensive/cheap/time-consuming/etc.  There's also transportation; what if anything is imported and what must be produced locally?  And then there are cultural norms.

Comment: you gave one piece of information, location, that covers a lot of things now you need two others. First is  history, is it a former colony and how did it interact with its neighbors, was it heavily involved in trade or isolationist. Do they have refrigeration. the second is, culture, Are there any major food taboos besides the common ones, is the society heavily class based or income based. with these questions you can narrow it down a lot.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## France and Germany are not that similar

There  are actually significant differences between France and Germany. The first is that more or less half of France is in the Mediterranean zone. The reason French cooking became so renowned in Europe is that it is the biggest country that straddles the climactic border between Warm Mediterranean, and Cool Oceanic.

There are many things that are available in France that are not available in Germany. First there are a lot more types of fish due to Altantic and Med coasts; northern European fish cuisine is basically herring and pickled herring. Second, many spices are grow wild in France: rosemary, thyme, oregano, lavender, savoury, saffron, etc. Traditional German food isn't known for any spices other than mustard.

Lastly, France has been cultivated for millennia, with forests cleared as far back as Caesar. That means lots of open plains for cattle. France is *boeuf* country. Germany, on the other hand, was mostly forest, well into the 1700s. The German population didn't really take off until after the 30 Years War. The animal of the forest is the pig. Thus, German cuisine has lots of schnitzel and sausage, and not a lot of beef.

## To get monsoon cuisine, find a monsoon climate

The Cerrado of Brazil is one of the wetter tropical savannah ecosystems, and might be categorized better as a tropical dry forest. Brasillia, the capital of Brazil, has [climate conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bras%C3%ADlia#Climate) typical of the region. The savannah is mostly forest, with denser gallery forests along rivers that remain wet year-round, and dryer parkland farther away from water sources.

Since there isn't much indigenous cuisine that we know about from the region, we can find a region with similar weather. [Bangkok, Thailand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bangkok#Climate) is reasonably close, as is [Hanoi, Vietnam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hanoi#Climate), [Lagos, Nigeria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagos#Climate) and [Kumasi, Ghana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kumasi#Climate).

This means we can look at [Thai](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thai_cuisine), [Vietnamese](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vietnamese_cuisine), [Yoruba](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoruba_culture#Cuisine) and [Akan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghanaian_cuisine) cuisines. A google search for those will give you good ideas for recipes and ingredients common to their cuisine.

Comment: Currently, I am working with Central Brazil, which, like you mentioned, has 4-8 months of rain followed by 8-4 months of dry

Comment: @TinyTrEs-2b Edited for recommended cuisines.